# Is there a way to achieve Dynamic Client Registration with IdentityServer?

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect, identityserver4

Our company has an SSO app that I'm looking to replace a significant chunk of the authentication pipeline with IdentityServer4 or 3. The version I'm replacing has its own custom implementation of Dynamic Client Registration (not to spec) and a UI to manage it.

There are a [number](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2021) [of](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/366) [Github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/308) [issues](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin/issues/15) across the IdentityServer project discussing the issue and the resolution appears to be that it hasn't been implemented and someone looking to use DCR should write their own implementation of the spec as an extension.

Am I correct that this is currently not possible and I would be better served creating my own DCR extension on Github for IdentityServer? Or have I missed something with my Google-fu and someone's already written an extension?

Note I'm happy to implement my own if it's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdentityServer 4 does not provide any implementation of dynamic client registration as they consider it out of scope for the project.
However you can implement your own, either as a middleware or as a MVC controller.

You need an endpoint that uses `ConfigurationDbContext` to the `Clients` table.

Source code for this is a issue on GitHub.
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1248

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer itself (the STS) has no implementation of OIDC DCR

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html

This is more of an admin type functionality.

Comment: I assume then that the identityserver3.admin project haven't implemented it either?

Answer (score 0):

The [Azure AD team has a sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) which authenticates against the AAD common endpoint and uses the returned claims to automatically provision new tenants. It might be a good place to start...